# Cannot find Component with Tag in reactjs TestUtils

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to figure out why this isn't working for a few days. I am having a really hard time getting `reactjs` `TestUtils` to work even when I reduced it to the most simple of examples:

```
describe('Layout', function() {
    it('try to find className', function(done) {
        var Wrapper = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return <div className="testWrapper">Hello <span>Jim</span></div>;
            }
        });

    var TestWrap = React.createClass({
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>Test this </p>
                    <Wrapper />
                </div>
            );
        }
    })

    var renderedTree = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<TestWrap />);
    var renderedMyComponent = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(renderedTree, 'div');
    done();
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Did not find exactly one match for tag:div
    at Object.ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:22398:14)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/Users/bli1/Development/QE/data-trader/data-trader/spec/views/layout.js:148:46)
```

Chrome 44.0.2403 (Mac OS X 10.10.4): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.041 secs / 0.007 secs)

Now when I change to look for `span`, it works...

Same code but replace

```
var renderedMyComponent = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(renderedTree, 'div');
```

with

```
var renderedMyComponent = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(renderedTree, 'span');
```

result:

`Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.039 secs / 0.007 secs)`

Comment: What's the result of `TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag()`?  I can't help but notice your example contains _two_ `div`s and that would violate the find function's assumption that there's only one result.

Comment: @DallonF took your suggestion and this was the output: http://dpaste.com/16QN283

Comment: @DallonF I think the `console.log()` is actually causing the error. Would you know why? Also, youre correct about the multiple `div`s

Comment: I have no idea, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 6):

The [document](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html) says

> Like scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag() but expects there to be **one** result...

Because there're two `<div>` blocks in your component, you have to use `scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag()` instead of `findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag()` to get the array and use `array[0]`, `array[1]` to get components in your `TestWrap` and `Wrapper` components.